# Raster Calculator in the Graphical Modeler of QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

How to convert this expression from raster calculator

```
("noise_heatmap_clip@1" <= 50) * 5 +
("noise_heatmap_clip@1" > 50 AND "noise_heatmap_clip@1" <= 100) * 4 +
("noise_heatmap_clip@1" > 100 AND "noise_heatmap_clip@1" <= 150) * 3 +
("noise_heatmap_clip@1" > 150 AND "noise_heatmap_clip@1" <= 200) * 2 +
("noise_heatmap_clip@1" > 200) * 1
```

in Graphical Modeler for QGIS 2.18 ?

Comment: I tried many times but unfortunately the output raster not have any values Nan values

Comment: This GDAL execution failed from log message panel

Comment: GDAL execution console output
   0 .. evaluation of calculation (A<=50) *5 + (A>50 logical_and A<=100) *4 + (A>100 logical_and A<=150) *3 + (A>150 logical_and A<=200) *2+ (A>200)*1 failed